# MySQL-python installation failed from python-alpine

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I'm going to build a docker image by the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
RUN set -ex \
        && apk --no-cache add --virtual build-dependencies \
        && pip install --no-cache-dir mysql-python
```

It downloads the package via:

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
```

and executes

```
python setup.py install
```

but it failes and returns the following error:

```
_mysql.c: In function '_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping':
_mysql.c:2005:41: error: 'MYSQL {aka struct st_mysql}' has no member named 'reconnect'
  if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                         ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

but when I try with:

```
FROM python:2.7
```

it prefectly works.
any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Solution is to use **mysqlclient** package instead of MySQL-python, it's a fork that solves multiple issues current MySQL-python has.

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Comment: This looks like the best answer. The fork is updated. The old library (which we've used) hasn't been released since 2014 - which may means it's pretty dead.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from this [comment](https://code.mythtv.org/trac/ticket/13093#comment:8) is that mysql and mariadb have a slightly different API and that this causes the compilation to fail in alpine.

Alpine already provides the `py-mysqldb` package that works fine, but it depends on its own `python2` package. My recommendation is to use something like:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk --no-cache add python2 py-mysqldb
```